# Changing CSS colors on runtime based on ajax response

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic Framework. I have this requirement where I get 3 colors in an object from the server. We'll call them `Color1,Color2,Color3` respectively. Now I want all the buttons using Color1, All the hyperlinks using Color2 and the background using Color3. It's more of a CSS question than an ionic one I guess. So how do I accomplish this using either Ionic Framework or Angular attribute manipulation maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the colors aren't fixed that's why you can't use simple css class so I'd suggest to use `ng-style`

http://plnkr.co/edit/0HT65VCUfstvbw0r2Teq?p=preview

```
  $scope.button = 'color': colors[0]
  $scope.link = 'background-color': colors[1]
  $scope.header = 
    'text-decoration': 'underline'
    'background-color': colors[1]
    color: colors[2]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up using after trying jQlite and what not.

Comment: @user3677331 It's a bad practice to manage your styles directly. You'd better use classes or just one class on the main container (e.g. `body`).

Answer (score -1):

Add needed CSS styles to `head`.
Then just add a CSS class to `body`.

```js
function addCssRule(rule, css) {
  css = JSON.stringify(css).replace(/"/g, "").replace(/,/g, ";");
  $("<style>").prop("type", "text/css").html(rule + css).appendTo("head");
}

$(function () {

  $('button.btn').click(function () {

    var colors = ['green', 'red', 'yellow'];

    addCssRule('body.color-scheme button', { 'background-color' : colors[0] });
    addCssRule('body.color-scheme a', { 'color' : colors[1] });
    addCssRule('body.color-scheme', { 'background-color' : colors[2] });

    var $body = $('body');
    $body.addClass('color-scheme');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Click me!</button>
<a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
```

My code is not for production use, it's just a demonstration. You need to optimize it.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. It's about AngularJS and also not for color values already known

Comment: `I have this requirement where I get 3 colors`. I understood that statement that you have particular colors.

Comment: Why in the world you want to use jQuery when angular solution is at hand?

Comment: @maurycy Sorry, I'm not experienced in AngularJS. But the question is not about AngularJS especially, it's about an algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

You can use angular.element which will delegates the task to jQuery or jqLite which is embedded in angularjs. See the example below for changing the color of all the buttons :

```
angular.element('button').css('background-color', color1);
```

Comment: Hi there - just to let you know we prefer posts without voting commentary and advice. Put it in the comments if you really must, but in my experience it rarely elicits answers from your voters anyway.